# Caret position relative to screen coordinates in javaFX

Tags: textarea, screen, javafx-8, caret

I am trying to find a way to get the corresponding screen location of the caret-position in a text area in JavaFX. I need the location to show Popups in text at the caret location.

I found request or it here:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090849

and some workarounds here:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2534556

They work somehow, but there are a few issues with location not updating correctly sometimes. Does anyone have a suggestion of how to get the caret position in terms of screen X and Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to follow-up with an answer to this question for TextField controls in JavaFX. I'm sure the same could apply to other text input controls as well. I got the idea from looking at some code that involved changing the default colour of the caret using a subclass of `TextFieldSkin` class. If you look closely, the `TextFieldSkin` superclass holds a reference to the `Path` instance which represents the caret in a protected field called `caretPath`. Although this is kind of a hack'ish solution, it does provide developers with the absolute coordinates of the Caret in a much safer way than most of the hacks I've seen out there.

```
public class TextFieldCaretControlSkin extends TextFieldSkin {
    public TextFieldCaretControlSkin(TextField textField, Stage stage) {
        super(textField);
        Popup popup = new Popup();

        // Make the popup appear to the right of the caret
        popup.setAnchorLocation(PopupWindow.AnchorLocation.CONTENT_BOTTOM_LEFT);
        // Make sure its position gets corrected to stay on screen if we go out of screen
        popup.setAutoFix(true);
        // Add list view (mock autocomplete popup)
        popup.getContent().add(new ListView<String>());

        // listen for changes in the layout bounds of the caret path
        caretPath.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, 
                                Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
                popup.hide();
                // get the caret's x position relative to the textfield.
                double x = newValue.getMaxX(); 
                // get the caret's y position relative to the textfield.
                double y = newValue.getMaxY(); 
                Point2D p = caretPath.localToScene(x, y);

                /*
                 * If the coordinates are negatives then the Path is being
                 * redrawn and we should just skip further processing.
                 */
                if (x == -1.0 || y == -1.0)
                    return;

                // show the popup at these absolute coordinates.                    
                popup.show(textField,
                        p.getX() + caretPath.getScene().getX() + 
                             caretPath.getScene().getWindow().getX(),
                        p.getY() + caretPath.getScene().getY() + 
                             caretPath.getScene().getWindow().getY() - 
                             newValue.getHeight()); // put the popup on top of the caret
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To use you'd have to embed this in some sort of subclassed text input control and remember to do `textField.setSkin(new TextFieldCaretControlSkin(textField))`. There may be better ways to do this since I am not a JavaFX expert but I just wanted to share this solution with the rest of the world just in case it provided some insight.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) to position a popup window 4px to the right of the caret:

```
InlineCssTextArea area = new InlineCssTextArea();
Popup popup = new Popup();
popup.getContent().add(new Label("I am a popup label!"));
area.setPopupWindow(popup);
area.setPopupAlignment(PopupAlignment.CARET_CENTER);
area.setPopupAnchorOffset(new Point2D(4, 0));
```

You still need to control the visibility of the popup window yourself by calling

```
popup.show(ownerWindow);
popup.hide();
```

See also this [working demo](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/blob/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/PopupDemo.java).